# Unable to play .avi file in video light box

Tags: jquery, lightbox, avi

I am trying to play .avi file in [video lightbox](http://videolightbox.com/) by over riding it's generated code

but I am not able to play that .avi video

what I did is change in generated index.html file like this

```
 <a class="voverlay" href="index_videolb/player.swf?url=video/101.avi&volume=100" title="101"><img src="index_videolb/thumbnails/101.png" alt="101" /><span></span></a>
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Please help me how to play .avi file in video lightbox jquery

I am willing to use any other lightbox which supports .avi file , but I didnt find it , It would be great help if you can help me to find any other supported jquery for the same

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVI is a container format. And have nothing to do with the codec. The video file is properly encoded with a codec that video lightbox doesnt support. Try another file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ,actually what I want is to play .avi file through lightbox jquery so is there not any other way so that I can play .avi file on lightbox jquery ?

Comment: It says on their webpage that they support flv, mp4, 3gp video files. So you need to change your avi file to a flv, mp4 or 3gp. You can do that with http://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: hmm ohk got your point :) ,but what I actually want is to to play the live stream on my website and that live streaming is stored in .avi format only so.....

Comment: A live stream in AVI, never seen that before. But as i said before AVI has nothing to do with what codec the video feed is encoded in.